# ApiKey response api/login Orocommerce

Tags: orocommerce

I am getting the apikey that generates the /api/login, but that apikey I don't see how to use it in the other endpoints since in the Docs it talks about making request with the OAuth2.

https://files.slack.com/files-pri/T11NA9FSN-F03CMAN5H6X/captura_desde_2022-04-22_15-38-11.png

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In case you need to use
generated via "api/login" method API key in the scope of Sandbox you should:

- generate API key via "api/login" method by passing login and password of customer user
- sign in with the same user or just refresh Sandbox page, in case you already signed in
  [image]
- after authentication method will be changed to WSSE (in case if it is still session switch it manually)
  [image]
- after WSSE will be used for every call
  [image]

In case you need to use WSSE authentication from code please see the next article (especially "Header Generation" part): https://doc.oroinc.com/api/authentication/wsse/